# how do i add AzureAutomation Resource to my ARM template project

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I create a new ARM template using VS2017 and would like to add Azure Automation resource as part of my template. When I right click and select add New Resource I do not see Azure Automation. How do I go about doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this - go to the documentation and copy\paste it.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts